# Add background image to wp8 app

Tags: c#, xaml, azure, windows-phone-8

Hello i tried to add background image to one of my project pages , I am new to xmal and i need some help to understand why i cant see the background when i run the emulator.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="ipublicSrv.Pages.MusicMenuPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="C:\Users\lior\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\IPubProject\ipublicSrv\ipublicSrv\Resources\24796-armin-van-buuren.jpg"
                    Stretch="UniformToFill" />
        </Grid.Background>
        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock Text="Music Menu" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">

        </Grid>
    </Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

[image]

Comment: check your ImageSource

Comment: i add the image to the projects resources

Comment: `ImageSource` should look like   `ImageSource="\\Resources\Resources\24796-armin-van-buuren.jpg"`

Comment: image source path is having issue. emulator is not able to read the location. check the path.

Comment: Right click on the image in your solution explorer. Click properties and make sure the Build Action is set to Resource and also Do Not Copy. Then do a rebuild of your solution

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using Image from Your Computer.Please add image in your project with Build type `Content`.then give correct path as :

```
ImageSource="/Resources/Images/yourImage.png //if you added image in `Resource/Image` folder.
```

Hope this Helps.Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the build action is set to "content". That might be causing the issue.
And also check the path of the image that you are using. It has to be inside your project. Ideally inside the assets folder. or somewhere separately. 
Hope it helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add your PC address. It won't run on emulator. Since the address isn't resolved. Add the background image in the Assets or any folder in your solution then use

```
ImageSource = "Assets/background.png"
```

Assuming you have image in `Assets` folder named `background.png`